# Getting the custom product attribute in the Checkout summary Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, checkout, attributes, data

I have a custom product attribute which we are using in place of name for some reason. I need to change this through  out the site. I got success in getting this in minicart , product and cart page.
but i am unable to find how it is getting render on the checkout summary section

for minicart it is rendering from the file

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/CustomerData/DefaultItem.php

```
protected function doGetItemData()
    {
       .......
        return [
            'options' => $this->getOptionList(),
            'qty' => $this->item->getQty() * 1,
            'item_id' => $this->item->getId(),
            'configure_url' => $this->getConfigureUrl(),
            'is_visible_in_site_visibility' => $this->item->getProduct()->isVisibleInSiteVisibility(),
            'product_name' => $this->item->getProduct()->getName(),
            'product_url' => $this->getProductUrl(),
            'product_has_url' => $this->hasProductUrl(),
           .....
    }
```

but in checkout summary i can't find how it works. Please suggest how can i achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a plugin for that. I wanted to add product flavor to order summary. This is the way I created a plugin and achieved what I wanted.

Vendor = Sejal

Files you need to create:

1. Registration.php : app\code\Sejal\Flavor\registration.php
2. di.xml : app\code\Sejal\Flavor\etc\di.xml
3. module.xml : app\code\Sejal\Flavor\etc\di.xml
4. ConfigProviderPlugin.php : app\code\Sejal\Flavor\Plugin\ConfigProviderPlugin.php
5. details.html : copy of vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\summary\item\details.html

you can override this file in your theme like this

app\design\frontend\Vendor\themename\Magento_Checkout\web\template\summary\item\details.html

Code:
registration.php

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Sejal_Flavor',
    __DIR__
);
```

di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider">
        <plugin name="AddAttPlug" type="Sejal\Flavor\Plugin\ConfigProviderPlugin" />
    </type>
</config>
```

module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Sejal_Flavor" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

ConfigProviderPlugin.php

```
<?php

namespace Sejal\Flavor\Plugin;

class ConfigProviderPlugin extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{

    public function afterGetConfig(\Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider $subject, array $result)
    {

        $items = $result['totalsData']['items'];

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        for($i=0;$i<count($items);$i++){

            $quoteId = $items[$i]['item_id'];
            $quote = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item')->load($quoteId);
            $productId = $quote->getProductId();
            $product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
            $productFlavours = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('flavors')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);         
            if($productFlavours == 'No' || $productFlavours == 'NA'){
                $productFlavours = '';
            }
            $items[$i]['flavor'] = $productFlavours;
        }
        $result['totalsData']['items'] = $items;
        return $result;
    }

}
```

details.html

Copy vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\summary\item\details.html in theme and add

```
<div class="product-item-flavor" data-bind="text: $parent.flavor"></div>
```

below

```
<strong class="product-item-name" data-bind="text: $parent.name"></strong>
```

That's it! 
Hope it helps!

Comment: did the same but not working.